# How to get products from Shopify api without /products.json

Tags: api, web-scraping, shopify

Is there any other way to get a product list from Shopify without `/products.json` or  `collections/....`?
Because `/products.json` responses can take anywhere from 300ms to 7000ms and `/some_kind_of_product/products.json` response time is from 0ms to 300ms.

Ms time is not because of servers or something. I mean when a new product is added in back-end, it takes time to /products.json(front-end) see new item.

And without `/admin`, as user

Comment: You can use the Ajax API to get the product without being logged in as the admin user. https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/ajax-api/reference/product

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use the [Storefront GrahpQL](https://shopify.dev/docs/storefront-api/reference) and get only the items you want.

You will need to build your query and create a Private App in order to use the Storefront Access Token.

Example request:

```
{
  products(first:10){
    edges {
      node {
        title
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Full request:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: 'https://YOUR_STORE.myshopify.com/api/graphql',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
      'X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token': 'STOREFRONT_ACCESS_TOKEN',
      'Content-Type': 'application/graphql',
  },
  data: `query {
    products(first:10){
      edges {
        node {
          title
        }
      }
    }
  }`,
})
.done(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
})
```

Comment: This is a great example of how to grab a product with graphql, but this example also exposes the storefront access token.

Comment: @kenput3r this is the `Storefront Access Token`, not the `Admin Access Token`, there is a huge difference - one can be used publicly on the Storefront, the other one should be used only in the back-end. So it's OK to expose a publicly available Storefront Access Token, that's the main idea of it - to be exposed. There are two separate GraphQL API I think you are confusing the Storefront GraphQL with the Admin GraphQL.

Comment: @drip depending on the permissions, you can still modify customers with that token though, can't you?

Comment: @kenput3r Yes and no - in order to "modify" the customer you need to request the customer token, which is generated by a request to the API with his username and password... good luck with getting those. The only point of the Storefront GraphQL existing is to be used on the front-end and you are saying don't use it there. You have a huge misunderstanding about this API, please read more about it since the comment section is not the place to explain it.